# Why are PDF bookmarks created using pdftk not showing in macOS Preview?

Tags: macos, pdf, pdftk

I'm trying to add Bookmarks with titles using the following command:

`pdftk A.pdf update_info metadata.txt output B.pdf`

When I check B.pdf's metadata, using `pdftk B.pdf data_dump output metadata_B.txt`, I see the lines I added:

```
BookmarkBegin
BookmarkTitle: title
BookmarkLevel: 1
BookmarkPageNumber: 1
```

But no bookmarks are shown when I open the file in Preview of macOS.

Comment: What about other viewers?

Comment: @notautogenerated I've tried with Acrobat Reader and a Google Chrome Extension called PDF Viewer. Both of them display bookmarks with no problems. Preview, Books, and Google Drive's PDF Viewer do not. I annotate and read PDFs using multiple devices and OSs, so I was hoping I could do it without having to install too many third-party software.

Comment: oh, then chances are it is just a naming issue. Bookmarks are called "Table of Contents" in Preview, while annotations are called bookmarks. I can add this as an answer if it solves the problem.

Comment: @notautogenerated No, they don't show up anywhere in Preview.

Comment: Well, sorry then, I am completely baffled.

Comment: Apple's concept of bookmarks in PDF files is their own, incompatible with actual bookmarks. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1221165

Comment: Thank you both for your comments! I tried it again after upgrading to Big Sur, and they showed up under Table of Contents, like @notautogenerated said. The problem might have been because I was on a beta version of the OS, previously.